# How can i get total sum from dynamic input in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

How can i get total sum from dynamic inputs in angular 2, have no idea to implement this. Thanks

[image]

```
//html component
<md-input-container style="width: 80px;">
                <input md-input class="debit" formControlName="debit" [(ngModel)]="debit[i]">
              </md-input-container>
```

Comment: provide your code pls

Comment: @ŌkamiXOukarin actually i dont have functionality yet, can u help me the idea about this implementation.

Comment: i have an example here with sum function
https://jsfiddle.net/g6xp1r52/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are creating debit text dynamically, and you also using `ngModel`, so you       can do this way

`(onChange) = "findSum()"`
for each input-text of debit
    and set `[(ngModel)]="totalVal"` for total input-text
    in .ts file do this

```
findSum(){sum= 0;
for( data of debit){total = total + data;}
totlaVal = total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using reactive form control then all the form control that are in the form tag have their value in in the form instance as below

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
            <input type="number" formControlName="value1"/>
            <input type="number" formControlName="value2"/>
</form>
```

and create the form from the form builder class

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            value1: [5, Validators.required],
            value2: [2, Validators.required]
});
```

and your form instance `myForm` will contain the updated values of all the controls in the property `myForm.value` and according to this example will contain `{ "value1": 2, "value2": 5 }` where you want total for that just use this property object and print the sum like

```
sum = Object.keys(this.myForm.value).reduce((prev, curr) => {
  return prev + this.myForm.value[curr]
}, 0);
```

Comment: The inputs are dynamic.

Comment: no matters . Your form instance always contains the inputs that are registered with that form